# How to change putty color scheme on linux user basis?

Tags: gnome, bash, ssh, putty

When I ssh into my server all but one of my users has the color scheme.  The one that doesn't, well everything shows up as gray text.  Is there a way I can change this color scheme?

Also, why would that one user's color scheme allow for only gray text when I ssh from putty, while the others have the different file types colored?  My server is ubuntu with gnome and when I go into the terminal, this user has a color scheme (ex. ls command lists folders as light blue and bold)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would set colors in ~/.bashrc

Perhaps copy the ~/.bashrc from another user or /etc/skel/.bashrc

What colors do you want to set ? Prompt? ls ?

Comment: I tried both, neither worked =(.  I just want the default colors that show up for all other users.  I haven't changed any of these settings (to my knowledge) for the user that doesn't have a color scheme showing up.

Comment: I understand "colors" are not working, but I can not tell from what you posted if the problem is with .bashrc or your putty configuration , nor am I certain what colors ? you mean colors in command output such as ls ? colors in the prompt ? Can you ssh in (rather then putty) and confirm that the .bashrc is the same between users and that you are not sourcing a file ?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was unsure what you were asking.  I mean the colors in the command output.  I just ssh'd and when I run ls, the output is colored for all but one user.  I don't think the problem lies in putty.  What do you mean by sourcing a file?  I deleted the .bashrc for the problem user and copied over a .bashrc from a user with the colored command output but I'm still having the same problem =(

Comment: Okay, I realized the problem.  There was a conflict w/ some stuff in .bash_profile, thanks for all your help =)

Comment: glad you got it sorted.